# how to separate arrays in ajax and assign it to variables

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

i have the code for fetching the whole array for my html.

```
$('#btnSubmit').on('click', function () {
    array = [];
    $('.getOrders').each(function () {
        array = $(this).val();

        //i did console.log in here and i got the whole results//

        console.log(array);
    });
});
```

in my controller:

```
$inc = $request->input('inc');
$inc2 = 1;
for ($inc2; $inc2 <= $inc; $inc2++) {
    $ix = ($request->input('i_name' . $inc2));
    $ix2 = ($request->input('quan' . $inc2));
    $ix3 = ($request->input('tot' . $inc2));
    $ix4 = ($request->input('id_categ' . $inc2));
    $ix5 = ($request->input('id_item' . $inc2));

    echo '<input type="hidden" name="order_name[]" id="order_name' . $inc2 . '" class="getOrders" value="' . $ix . '" disabled>';
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="item_quan[]" id="item_quan' . $inc2 . '" class="getOrders" value="' . $ix2 . '" disabled>';
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="price_tot[]" id="price_tot' . $inc2 . '" class="getOrders" value="' . $ix3 . '" disabled>';
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="id_categ[]" id="id_categ' . $inc2 . '" class="getOrders" value="' . $ix4 . '" disabled>';
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="id_item[]" id="id_item' . $inc2 . '" class="getOrders" value="' . $ix5 . '" disabled>';

}
echo '<input type="hidden" id="inc" value="' . $inc . '" disabled>';

return view('show_sales')->with([
    'name'   => $request->input('customer_name'),
    'or_no'  => $request->input('or_number'),
    'total'  => $request->input('getItemPrice'),
    'change' => $request->input('change'),
]);
```

how can i slice the whole array and assign a value to it so i can store it on specific columns on my database?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. You don't have a 'whole array' - you define `array` as an array, but you immediately overwrite it in each iteration of your loop with the string value of each element...?

Comment: shouldn't you pushing those values inside the array instead of overwriting them every iteration, and what is that echoed html doing inside your controller? shouldn't that be inside the view instead, btw really don't need to separate the array that you're sending, just send them all and let PHP do that separation and saving

Comment: i want to separate the $array value

Comment: Can you post the complete form you are using? If I understood your question you want to separate the request per model and not per field, right?

Answer (score 1):

First problem is  your JS you should use `push()` :

```
$('#btnSubmit').on('click', function () {
    array = [];
    $('.getOrders').each(function (key,value) {
        array.push($(this).val());

    });
        console.log(array);

});
```

after that just use a simple `Ajax` call and send your `array` as data